# How to convert two column .csv file to xml document

Tags: .net, xml, csv

Is it possible to convert a .csv file into .xml doc file? If is it possible can any one please help me regarding, please.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Reading the .csv file? Writing the XML?

Comment: the below answer posted by Prakash Patani is very useful to me thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you first need to read .csv file into datatable and then from datatable you can write xml file. use below code as per your requirement

```
public void CreateXmlFile()
{
    DataSet dataset = GetDataSet(@"D:\my_data.csv");
    dataset.Tables[0].WriteXml(@"D:\my_data.xml", true);

}
public DataSet GetDataSet(string filename)
{
    string connString =
      string.Format(
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Text;",
        Path.GetDirectoryName(filename));

    string cmdString =
      string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", Path.GetFileName(filename));

    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(cmdString, conn);
        adapter.Fill(dataset, "Test");



        conn.Close();
    }
    return dataset;
}
```

Hope this will helps you...happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public static void ConvertCSVToXML()
{
      String[] FileContent = File.ReadAllLines(@"G:\TEMP\test.csv");

      XElement xElm = new XElement("RootNodeName",
                          from items in FileContent
                          let fields = items.Split(',')
                          select new XElement("Item",
                             new XElement("ID", fields[0]),
                             new XElement("Name", fields[1]))
                          );

      XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"), xElm);
      xDoc.Save(@"G:\Temp\test.xml");
 }
```